# Incrementing a counter

Tags: javascript, increment

I have the following code

```js
class battleShips {
  constructor(squareNr) {
    this.squareNr = squareNr;
    this.createField();
  }
  createField() {
    let shipsCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.squareNr; i++) {
      let fieldSquare = document.createElement("div");
      fieldSquare.className = "squareStyle";
      document.querySelector(".arrayWrap").appendChild(fieldSquare);
      fieldSquare.setAttribute("value", "false");
      this.selectShips(fieldSquare, shipsCount);
    }
  }
  selectShips(square, count) {
    square.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (square.getAttribute("value") === "false") {
        square.setAttribute("value", "true");
        square.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
        document.querySelector(".shipCounter").textContent = "You have selected " + count + " ships";
      } else {
        square.setAttribute("value", "false");
        square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        count -= 1;
        document.querySelector(".shipCounter").textContent = "You have selected " + count + " ships";
      }
    })
  }
}

var a = new battleShips(25);
```

```css
.arrayWrap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: black solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.squareStyle {
  height: 98px;
  width: 98px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrayWrap"></div>
<p class="shipCounter"></p>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that every time you click a square, the `shipsCount` variable increments by 1, but as you can see in the paragraph below, and if I log the count variable it only increments once, not going past 1.

What can I change in order for it to work as desired?

Comment: Your count variable needs to be declared in a higher scope.

Comment: Have you checked console output for errors?

Comment: Scott is right, count can be a "Global variable" cause actually, your are declaring it everytime you click.

Comment: @HBP Yes, there are no errors.

Comment: @ScottMarcus is there any way I can achieve this without having to declare it globaly ?

Comment: @TudorApostol You can still declare it locally if you want, e.g., wrapping your entire code with a new function? Or declaring that variable with `const` or `let`

Comment: Just wrap it all in another function and declare the variable there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store `count` as property of your class instances. Until now, you have it just local, so it is removed after the click function has finished. So, just add the following line to your constructor:

```
this.count = 0;
```

And use it in your increment/decrement functionality. That's it! ;-)

Edit: That's not all. We have also an unresolved scope issue here. The keyword `this` has another context inside an event handler. This `this` is not the class scope as excepted, it is the scope of that event handler, in our case the click handler. Pretty nasty JavaScript issue that many developers traps into. So did I this time. Sorry for that. Below you see a fully working code example in plain old JavaScript. Not a nice way to give the event handler every time the instance of that class, but it works (see consoloe logs, it is really the same instance which counts up or down):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        class battleShips
        {
          constructor(squareNr)
          {
            this.squareNr = squareNr;
            this.createField();
            this.count = 0;
          }

          createField()
          {
            let shipsCount = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.squareNr; i++) {
              let fieldSquare = document.createElement("div");
              fieldSquare.className = "squareStyle";
              document.querySelector(".arrayWrap").appendChild(fieldSquare);
              fieldSquare.setAttribute("value", "false");
              this.selectShips(fieldSquare, this);
            }
          }

          selectShips(square, battleShipsInstance)
          {
            square.addEventListener(
                "click",
                function() {
                    if (square.getAttribute("value") === "false") {
                        square.setAttribute("value", "true");
                        square.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                        battleShipsInstance.count++;
                        console.log("Battleships count=", battleShipsInstance.count);
                        console.log("Battleships instance", battleShipsInstance);
                        document.querySelector(".shipCounter")
                            .textContent = "You have selected "
                            + battleShipsInstance.count
                            + " ships";
                    } else {
                        square.setAttribute("value", "false");
                        square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                        battleShipsInstance.count--;
                        document.querySelector(".shipCounter")
                            .textContent = "You have selected "
                            + battleShipsInstance.count
                            + " ships";
                    }
                }
            );
          }
        }

        document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded",
            function(event) {
                var a = new battleShips(25);
            }
        );
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .arrayWrap {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            border: black solid;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .squareStyle {
            height: 98px;
            width: 98px;
            border: 1px black solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="arrayWrap"></div>
    <p class="shipCounter"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your method but now I get NaN when I log this.count.

Comment: Then it is not intialized correctly. NaN is the short form for not a number. Be sure you pre initialize the class variable with a number before using it.

Comment: Well, I followed your advice and put this.count = 0 in the constructor.

Comment: @TudorApostol You were right, see my edited post for an full working example.

Comment: I solved it using () => instead of function() in square.addEventListener

Comment: Ok, also a nice way. If I solved your problem, please give me the green finishing hook.